# Responsive boxes and text not lining up

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Currently having a very annoying and tough problem in CSS.

Basically i have 2 rows, 6 boxes.

[image]

I haven't worked on the 2nd row yet as I'm finalizing the first box in the top row, before copy/pasting the code.

The problem i'm having is the width of the text.

This is what happens when you make the browser smaller:

[image]

The text should NOT be disappearing as their is still enough box space left. At this point the browser isn't even half of my macbook pro's screen, the browser is roughly 70% of the screen, but yet the boxes text already disappears?

How can i make these 2 rows of 6 boxes responsive to at least half of my screen? then from there just dealing with having them line up vertically, one box at a time (for phones).

I'm literally been messing with the css for 2 hours and have no idea, someone please help! I'm very new to CSS, building this website for my I.T company, and eventually want to do web development, so I put off posting here for a while, but am definitely out of ideas.

My html:

```
<head>
        <title>Microfuse Solutions - Home</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />


        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css" type="text/css" />

        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Jura:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <header class="header">
        <div class="mainheader">
            <nav>
                <h1>MICROFUSE SOLUTIONS.</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">PC Repairs</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Networking & Internet</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Home & Work Servers</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Support Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Website Development</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Our Team</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Our Story</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Our Portfolio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
                        </ul></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <div class="separator"></div>

            <div class="subheader">
                <div class="left-content">
                    <h1><b>Hello.</b></h1>
                    <h2>Welcome to MICROFUSE</h2>

                    <p>We assist individuals and businesses in a wide range of technical problems.<br/> We provide a fast, affordable, and reliable service, that comes with a guarantee for your problem to be fixed.<br/> If we do not fix your problem, then we do not charge you.</p>
                </div>

                <div class="padding"></div>

                <div class="right-content">
                    <img src="images/subheaderlogo.png"/>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </header>


    <div class="content">

    <div class="firstsection">
        <div class="top-row">
            <h2> What do we do? </h2>
            <div class="left-box-container">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="images/columns/websites.png">
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                    <h1><a href="#">Mobile Solutions</a></h1>
                    <ul>
                        <li><img src="images/columns/plus.png"/>No fix no fee!</li>
                    <li><img src="images/columns/plus.png"/>Fix your tech onsite</li>
                    <li><img src="images/columns/plus.png"/>Flexible timeframes</li>
                    <li><img src="images/columns/plus.png"/>Competetive prices</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="middle-box-container">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="images/columns/websites.png">
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                    <h1><a href="#">PC Repairs</a></h1>
                    <h4><img src="images/columns/plus.png"/>No fix no fee!</h4>
                    <h4><img src="images/columns/plus.png"/>Fix your tech onsite</h4>
                    <h4><img src="images/columns/plus.png"/>Flexible timeframes</h4>
                    <h4><img src="images/columns/plus.png"/>Competetive prices</h4>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="right-box-container">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="images/columns/websites.png">
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                    <h1><a href="#">Mobile Solutions</a></h1>
                    <h4><img src="images/columns/plus.png"/>No fix no fee!</h4>
                    <h4><img src="images/columns/plus.png"/>Fix your tech onsite</h4>
                    <h4><img src="images/columns/plus.png"/>Flexible timeframes</h4>
                    <h4><img src="images/columns/plus.png"/>Competetive prices</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="bottom-row">
            <div class="left-box-container">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="images/columns/websites.png">
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                    <h1><a href="#">Mobile Solutions</a></h1>
                    <h4><img src="images/columns/plus.png"/>No fix no fee!</h4>
                    <h4><img src="images/columns/plus.png"/>Fix your tech onsite</h4>
                    <h4><img src="images/columns/plus.png"/>Flexible timeframes</h4>
                    <h4><img src="images/columns/plus.png"/>Competetive prices</h4>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="middle-box-container">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="images/columns/websites.png">
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                    <h1><a href="#">Mobile Solutions</a></h1>
                    <h4><img src="images/columns/plus.png"/>No fix no fee!</h4>
                    <h4><img src="images/columns/plus.png"/>Fix your tech onsite</h4>
                    <h4><img src="images/columns/plus.png"/>Flexible timeframes</h4>
                    <h4><img src="images/columns/plus.png"/>Competetive prices</h4>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="right-box-container">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="images/columns/websites.png">
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                    <h1><a href="#">Mobile Solutions</a></h1>
                    <h4><img src="images/columns/plus.png"/>No fix no fee!</h4>
                    <h4><img src="images/columns/plus.png"/>Fix your tech onsite</h4>
                    <h4><img src="images/columns/plus.png"/>Flexible timeframes</h4>
                    <h4><img src="images/columns/plus.png"/>Competetive prices</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <center><div class="contact-text">
        <p> Can we help?</p>
        <p><a href="contact.html">Contact us</a> now!</p>
        </div></center>
    </div>
</div>

    <footer class="mainfooter">
        <div class="top-row">
            <p class="short-text">Like this website? Thanks, we designed it ourselves.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-row">
            <p class="copyright"> Copyright &copy; 2015 Microfuse Solutions | ABN 82 681 365 983</p>
        </div>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

My css:

```
/*
    Business Website
    Author: Joel Male;
    Date Started: 20/06/2015;
    Date Finished: **;
*/
/*
    ////////////////////////////////////
    /////////// WEB STUFF //////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////
*/
@font-face {
    font-family: BebasFont;
    src: url("../fonts/bebas-font.TTF");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Derive;
    src: url("../fonts/derive.TTF");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: RobotoBold;
    src: url("../fonts/Robot-Bold.TTF");
}
@font-face {
    font-family: RobotoRegular;
    src: url("../fonts/Robot-Regular.TTF");
}
/*
    ////////////////////////////////////
    ////// HANDLE DEFAULT MARKUPS //////
    ////////////////////////////////////
*/
body {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000305;
    font-size: 87.5%;
    font-family: Arial, 'Lucida Sans Unicode';
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

a { text-decoration: none }
a:link,
a:visited { }
a:hover,
a:active { }
/*
    ////////////////////////////////////
    //// HANDLE HEADER/CONTAINER ///////
    ////////////////////////////////////
*/
header {
    margin: 0 auto; /* Centers the page */
    width: 100%;
    clear: both; /* Nothing floats on the page */
}
.content {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
/*
    ////////////////////////////////////
    ////// HANDLE THE SEPARATORS ///////
    ////////////////////////////////////
*/
.mainheader .separator {
    margin-left: 15%;
    width: 70%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #CF5C3F;
}
.padding {
    width: 5%;
}
/*
    ////////////////////////////////////
    ////// HANDLE MAINHEADER HERE //////
    ////////////////////////////////////
*/
.mainheader {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #022930;
    height: 450px;
}
.mainheader nav {
    padding-top: 2%;
    height: 40px;
}
.mainheader nav h1 {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'BebasFont';
    margin-top: -12px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 15%;
    font-size: 40px;
}
.mainheader nav ul {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 15% 0 0;
}
.mainheader nav ul li {
    font-family: 'Jura', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    display: inline;
}
.mainheader nav ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.mainheader nav a:link,
.mainheader nav a:visited {
    color: #FFF;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
.mainheader nav li:hover>a,
.mainheader nav a:active,
.mainheader nav .active a:link,
.mainheader nav .active a:visited {
    background-color: #CF5C3F;
    text-shadow: none;
}
/*
    ////////////////////////////////////
    //// HANDLE THE DROP DOWN MENUS ////
    ////////////////////////////////////
*/
.mainheader nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block; /* THIS SHOULD HANDLE THE SHOWING OF THE MENU */
    padding-right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 27px;
    left: 0;
}
.mainheader nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #666;
}
.mainheader nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
    padding-right: 0;
    min-width: 190px;
}
.mainheader nav ul ul li:hover {
    background-color: #CF5C3F;
}
/*
    ////////////////////////////////////
    //// HANDLE THE SUBHEADER CONTENT //
    ////////////////////////////////////
*/
.mainheader .subheader {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display: flex;
}
.mainheader .subheader .left-content {
    padding-left: 15%;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
.mainheader .subheader .left-content h1 {
    margin-top: 0;
    font-family: 'BebasFont';
    font-size: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    color: #FFF;
}
.mainheader .subheader .left-content h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
    font-family: 'BebasFont';
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    color: #FFF;
}
.mainheader .subheader .left-content p {
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'Jura';
}
.mainheader .subheader .right-content {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
}
.mainheader .subheader .right-content img {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 26.5%;
    height: 300px;
}
/*
    ////////////////////////////////////
    //// HANDLE THE FIRST SECTION //////
    ////////////////////////////////////
*/
.firstsection {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px 0 20px 0;
}
.firstsection h2 {
    font-family: 'BebasFont';
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 0 0 20px 40px;
}
/*
    ////////////////////////////////////
    ///////////// TOP ROW //////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////
*/
.firstsection .top-row {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}
.firstsection .top-row .left-box-container {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 40px;
    width: 30%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 0px 29px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
    -moz-box-shadow: 7px 0px 29px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
    box-shadow: 7px 0px 29px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
    }
.firstsection .top-row .left-box-container .image img {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 140px;
}
.firstsection .top-row .left-box-container .text {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.firstsection .top-row .left-box-container .text h1 {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
.firstsection .top-row .left-box-container .text a  {
    color: black;
}
.firstsection .top-row .left-box-container .text a:hover  {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.firstsection .top-row .left-box-container .text ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 3px 0 0 0;
}
.firstsection .top-row .left-box-container .text ul li {
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.8em;
}
.firstsection .top-row .left-box-container .text ul li img {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
}

.firstsection .top-row .middle-box-container {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 40px;
    width: 30%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 0px 29px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
    -moz-box-shadow: 7px 0px 29px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
    box-shadow: 7px 0px 29px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
    }
.firstsection .top-row .middle-box-container .image img {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 140px;
}
.firstsection .top-row .middle-box-container .text {
    float: right;
}
.firstsection .top-row .middle-box-container .text h1 {
    font-size: 22px;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    margin-right: 100px;
}
.firstsection .top-row .middle-box-container .text a  {
    color: black;
}
.firstsection .top-row .middle-box-container .text a:hover  {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.firstsection .top-row .middle-box-container .text h4 {
    margin: 3px 0 0 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.firstsection .top-row .middle-box-container .text h4 img {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
}

.firstsection .top-row .right-box-container {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 40px;
    width: 30%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 0px 29px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
    -moz-box-shadow: 7px 0px 29px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
    box-shadow: 7px 0px 29px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
    }
.firstsection .top-row .right-box-container .image img {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 140px;
}
.firstsection .top-row .right-box-container .text {
    float: right;
}
.firstsection .top-row .right-box-container .text h1 {
    font-size: 22px;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
.firstsection .top-row .right-box-container .text a  {
    color: black;
}
.firstsection .top-row .right-box-container .text a:hover  {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.firstsection .top-row .right-box-container .text h4 {
    margin: 3px 0 0 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.firstsection .top-row .right-box-container .text h4 img {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
}
/*
    ////////////////////////////////////
    //////////// BOTTOM ROW ////////////
    ////////////////////////////////////
*/
.firstsection .bottom-row {
    margin: 90px 0 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
}
.firstsection .bottom-row .left-box-container {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 40px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 0px 29px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
    -moz-box-shadow: 7px 0px 29px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
    box-shadow: 7px 0px 29px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
    }
.firstsection .bottom-row .left-box-container .image img {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 140px;
}
.firstsection .bottom-row .left-box-container .text {
    float: right;
}
.firstsection .bottom-row .left-box-container .text h1 {
    font-size: 22px;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
.firstsection .bottom-row .left-box-container .text a  {
    color: black;
}
.firstsection .bottom-row .left-box-container .text a:hover  {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.firstsection .bottom-row .left-box-container .text h4 {
    margin: 3px 0 0 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.firstsection .bottom-row .left-box-container .text h4 img {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
}
.firstsection .bottom-row .middle-box-container {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 40px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 0px 29px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
    -moz-box-shadow: 7px 0px 29px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
    box-shadow: 7px 0px 29px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
    }
.firstsection .bottom-row .middle-box-container .image img {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 140px;
}
.firstsection .bottom-row .middle-box-container .text {
    float: right;
}
.firstsection .bottom-row .middle-box-container .text h1 {
    font-size: 22px;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
.firstsection .bottom-row .middle-box-container .text a  {
    color: black;
}
.firstsection .bottom-row .middle-box-container .text a:hover  {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.firstsection .bottom-row .middle-box-container .text h4 {
    margin: 3px 0 0 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.firstsection .bottom-row .middle-box-container .text h4 img {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
}
.firstsection .bottom-row .right-box-container {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 40px;
    width: 350px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 0px 29px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
    -moz-box-shadow: 7px 0px 29px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
    box-shadow: 7px 0px 29px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
    }
.firstsection .bottom-row .right-box-container .image img {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 140px;
}
.firstsection .bottom-row .right-box-container .text {
    float: right;
}
.firstsection .bottom-row .right-box-container .text h1 {
    font-size: 22px;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
.firstsection .bottom-row .right-box-container .text a  {
    color: black;
}
.firstsection .bottom-row .right-box-container .text a:hover  {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.firstsection .bottom-row .right-box-container .text h4 {
    margin: 3px 0 0 0;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
.firstsection .bottom-row .right-box-container .text h4 img {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    float: left;
}
/*
    ////////////////////////////////////
    /////////// CONTACT TEXT ///////////
    ////////////////////////////////////
*/
.firstsection .contact-text {
    margin: 15px 0 0 0;
}
.firstsection .contact-text p {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Jura';
}
.firstsection .contact-text p a {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Jura';
}
.firstsection .contact-text p a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #CF5C3F;
}
/*
    ////////////////////////////////////
    //////// HANDLE THE FOOTER /////////
    ////////////////////////////////////
*/
.mainfooter {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    float: left;
    background-color: #022930;
    color: white;
}
.mainfooter a { color: #FFF }
.mainfooter .top-row {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}
.mainfooter .bottom-row {
    width: auto;
    height: 50%;
}
.mainfooter .top-row h1 {
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-bottom: 3%;
}
.mainfooter p {
    font-family: 'BebasFont';
}
.mainfooter .top-row .short-text {
    padding-left: 15%;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}
.mainfooter .bottom-row .copyright {
    padding-left: 15%;
    margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}
/*
    ////////////////////////////////////
    /// HANDLE PHONE/SMALLER SCREENS ///
    ////////////////////////////////////
*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width: 600px) { 
    .body {
        width: 90%;
        font-size: 95%;
    }
    .mainheader img { width: 30% }
    .mainheader nav {
        background: #666;
        height: 200px;
        line-height: 30px;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .mainheader nav ul {
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
    .mainheader nav li {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: 0 auto;
    }
    .mainheader nav a:link,
    .mainheader nav a:visited {
        color: #FFF;
        display: block;
        height: 30px;
        padding: 5px 0;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .mainheader nav a:active,
    .mainheader nav .active a:link,
    .mainheader nav .active a:visited {
        background: #CF5C3F;
        color: #fff;
        text-shadow: none !important;
    }
    .mainheader nav li a {
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    }
    .content {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        margin-top: 2%;
    }
    .top-content {
        background-color: #FFF;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 3% 5%;
        margin-top: 2%;
    }
    .bottom-content {
        background-color: #FFF;
        border-radius: 5px;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 3% 5%;
        margin-top: 2px;
    }
}
```

Getting these 6 boxes to be responsive to at least a tablet view (while maintaining the same layout) and then vertical 1 box at a time for a phone, is pretty much the last problem i have to deal with before almost completing the website.

I also noticed at (as you can see in the second box) if i change the header name to anything, it screws up the layout of the box.

Anyway pls help :( i tried my best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use floats for the boxes, uses either a CSS `table` or `flexbox`:

Example HTML

```css
* { margin:0; padding:0; }

/* css table */
.box { display: table; border: 1px solid #000; background: #ccc;}
.box>div { display: table-cell; }
.box-img { width: 150px; background: url(http://www.fillmurray.com/150/150) center no-repeat; }
.box-text { padding: 10px; }

/* flexbox */
.flexbox-box { display: flex; align-items: center; border: 1px solid #000; background: #ccc;}
.flexbox-box-img { flex: 0 0 150px; height: 150px; background: url(http://www.fillmurray.com/150/150) center no-repeat; }
.flexbox-box-text { flex: 1 1 auto; padding: 10px;}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-img">
  </div>
  <div class="box-text">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce et elit id justo porta interdum. Cras elementum, arcu eu pulvinar maximus, massa ipsum gravida risus, eget ultricies libero augue sed magna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer eget pharetra dolor. Quisque lobortis porttitor molestie. Aliquam non sagittis lorem. Proin faucibus magna    
  </div>
</div>

<div class="flexbox-box">
  <div class="flexbox-box-img">
  </div>
  <div class="flexbox-box-text">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce et elit id justo porta interdum. Cras elementum, arcu eu pulvinar maximus, massa ipsum gravida risus, eget ultricies libero augue sed magna. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer eget pharetra dolor. Quisque lobortis porttitor molestie. Aliquam non sagittis lorem. Proin faucibus magna      
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried implementing this into my code, but I couldn't get it to work. How can I implement it to work with my current code?

Answer (score 0):

```
/* for 700px or less */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

    #content {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
    }

    #middle {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
        margin-left: 0px;
    }

    #sidebar {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
    }

}
```

**[FIddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/rgj8b5ks/)**

**Note** : A prototype has been shown in Fiddle.